# Getting info - if a folder exist ignoring varible

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement, cmd, directory

I am making a batch file which tells if a folder exist.
`\..\` - Consider is path is constant on all computers.
`\..\CompanyName\`- Now i can check if this folder exists.
`\..\Companyname\Productname version x.x.x` - Now I cannot check if "product" exits because if i use `if exist "%constantpath%\Productname version 1.2.3" (code block)`
condition will only return true if Whole Name Matchs. If Productname version is 1.2.4 it will return false.so that batch file is good as dead.When i tried
`set dest=Productname Version 1.2.3`

```
set temp=%dest:~0,11% // which means "Productname"
```

`if exist "%constantpath%\%temp% (code block)`
to see if only "Product name Exists
it returns with error
Syntax of command is incorrect. i think path is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so that batch file is good as dead.

*There's life in the old dog yet.*

`if exist` can not work with wildcards, but `dir` can:

```
dir /s "%constantpath%\Productname version 1.*" >nul && (
  echo yes 
) || (
  echo no
)
```

This example will check for version 1.x.x

`"%constantpath%\Productname*"` will check for any version (with or without the string `version ...`. Adapt to your needs.

In case you need the complete name:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /s /b "%constantpath%\Productname version 1.*"` do set "fullname=%%i"
```

Comment: If exsit definitely works with wildcards.Try `if exist "c:\wind*" echo #` .

Comment: `if exist "c:\windows\" echo yes` works, while `if exist ""c:\wind*\" echo yes` doesn't. With `dir /ad` you can be sure, it's a directory, not a file without extension.

Answer (score 1):

`if exist` accept wild cards so you can try:

```
if exist "%constantpath%\Productname version ?.?.?" (
  echo it exists
)
```

It also work with non normalized paths so you can use things like `\..\`

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using powershell for this, i had to do something recently similar because i needed to run an installer that could be in a various location but the first portion would always remain the same. It would be as follows.

```
$BaseDir = "\..\CompanyName\"
$NameToFind = "ProductName"

$MyVariable = Get-ChildItem $BaseDir -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -like ($NameToFind)}

$productVersion = $myvariable.FullName

Write-Host $productVersion
```